# RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: BAN_MEMBERS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: BAN_MEMBERS.
    at PermissionsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:172:11)
    at PermissionsBitField.has (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:60:28)
    at PermissionsBitField.has (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\PermissionsBitField.js:92:82)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\commands\utility\server.js:9:39)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\index.js:62:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:354:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:238:12) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}
```

while executing

```js
if (!interaction.member.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
    return interaction.reply('You do not have the required permissions to use this command.');
}
```

I was trying to make banning command. I've added `GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans` to intents but it says that its deprecated.

Comment: What version of DiscordJS you are using and can you show where you set GatewayIntents ?

Comment: v14
```const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans] });```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.js v14 the permission is called `BanMembers`.
You can see all permission names [here](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-payloads/common#PermissionFlagsBits)

```js
if (!interaction.member.permissions.has('BanMembers')) {
    return interaction.reply('You do not have the required permissions to use this command.');
}
```